In VS Code How Can I Fix a "Module Not Found" Error For a File That Exists?
I have a Typescript-using codebase that imports CSS files using React CSS modules.  I have tons of these CSS imports throughout my code, and none get any errors ... except every once in awhile one does:

What's so strange is that the file does exist, and the path for it (./IntegrationAssetCard.module.css) is about as simple as it gets.  I can even CMD + Click on the import, and (despite having a red squiggly underline) VS Code will take me to the file!
It seems like this is a Typescript error, but I've tried restarting my Typescript server (inside VS Code), and that hasn't helped.  Can anyone suggest why VS Code would think one specific CSS file isn't there when it it is ... or suggest how I can debug things to figure it out why?

do you have a *.d.ts file that might have something like declare module '*.module.css' in it? Where is that file? What's in it?

I do have a .d.ts file which has declare module '*.md'; and declare module '*.svg', but there's no declaration for CSS.  I am using Vite, and Vite might be bringing in that declaration somehow ... but if it is I'm not sure how, as I don't see any sort of css plugin in my vite config.
